# Left align table to margin with newcolumntype

Tags: tables

I am trying to make simple tables that span the width of my body text with the `\newcolumntype` command in LaTeX.

In the left column, I would like the text to be right-aligned (within the column). However, I'd like the left-hand side of this column to align with my left margin.

In the right column, I'd like the text to be left-aligned, and continue until it reaches the right margin.

I'd like there to be a small bit of padding between the two columns.

My current code is as follows:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.7\textwidth}}
```

Tables are:

```
\begin{tabular}{L!{}R}
...
\end{tabular}
```

The problem I am having is that the left-hand column will not align with my left margin in my document. Instead, it severely indents. I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Using as the table preamble `\begin{tabular}{@{}LR@{}}` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard! I'm still seeing an indent on my tabular environment when I use this preamble. I'm using the longtable environment, if relevant! Is there some way to remove this indent in longtable?

Comment: Maybe you have a blank line  before your long table? Or I would suggest using the `xltabular` environment (homonymous package), which nrings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. The table should begin with `\begin{xltabular}{@{}>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\arraybackslash}X@{}}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Bernard! When I use xltabular some of the command `begin{xltabular}...' that you provided prints to the page instead of "working" for me! So I'm not sure what's up, unfortunately!

Comment: I think one possibility is that I'm looking in the wrong place for the problem... I see my tables as "indented" compared to my section headings, which are left-aligned. But it's possible my section headings are "too" left-aligned compared to all of my other tables and body text--so they are the problem. In this case, I'm not sure how to push them further right, so that they align with the tables! This may be my issue, though--advice appreciated, if you have any!

Comment: Didn't you forget the `\` before begin? B. t.w., the syntax is the  same as for longtable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you employ a `longtable` environment?

Comment: I've been using a `longtable` environment so that the content of my tables automatically continues on the next page, if they end up being long (which I expect they will, for this paper). However, if you have an alternative suggestion that might be better, I would appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabular*` rather than a `tabular` environment and set the overall width of the `tabular*` environment to `\textwidth`.

Since you wrote, "In the right column, I'd like the text to be left-aligned", I think the column definition should be

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright}p{0.7\textwidth}}
```

rather than just

```
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.7\textwidth}}
```

And do insert the instruction `\noindent` right before `\begin{tabular*}`.

The framelines in the following screenshot are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded in the underlying brief test document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,showframe,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft} p{0.225\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright}p{0.725\textwidth}}
\begin{document}

\noindent% <-- very important
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} LR @{}}
\lipsum[1][2-4] & \lipsum[2]  \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's how you might achieve the same outcome while using a `longtable` environment instead of a `tabular*` environment. (I'm not posting a second screenshot, as it would be identical to the one shown above.)

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} LR @{}}
\lipsum[1][2-4] & \lipsum[2]  \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I will play around with it and see how it works for me.

Comment: @AnnaJones - I've provided an addendum to show how the same result may be achieved with a `longtable` environment.

Comment: Hello @Mico! Your `longtable` strategy worked for me, in that the left column has now stopped indenting! Thanks very much. However, now when I have more than two rows in a table, the table does not seem to understand how to "end" one row and go to the next. E.g., if I type `textA & textB \\ textC & text D`, sometimes `textC` ends up in column 1 and/or in other odd places in the table where it does not belong, and I get the "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" warning. If you have any advice, I would appreciate it greatly!

Comment: @AnnaJones - I'm afraid you haven't provided enough information to allow a proper diagnosis of the situation. May I ask you to post a new query, ideally in the form of a compilable test document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and generates the problem behavior you wish to fix? Thanks.